# Need to understand the functionality of string.count() function

Tags: python, string, conceptual, concept

I was trying to understand the functioning of string.count basically
The documented definition of it is

> string.count(s, sub[, start[, end]])
>   Return the number of (non-overlapping) occurrences of substring sub in string s[start:end]. Defaults for start and end and
>   **interpretation of negative values are the same as for slices.**

Now what's the exact meaning of last line here which is bold actually. I did some random experiment with this function

```
In [19]: a
Out[19]: 'ab'
In [23]: string.count(a,'ab'[1:3])
Out[23]: 1

In [24]: string.count(a,'ab'[1:1])
Out[24]: 3

In [25]: string.count(a,'ab'[-1:1])
Out[25]: 3

In [26]: string.count(a,'ab'[-1:0])
Out[26]: 3

In [27]: string.count(a,'ab'[1:4])
Out[27]: 1

In [28]: string.count(a,'ab'[1:100])
Out[28]: 1

In [29]: string.count(a,'ab'[100:100])
Out[29]: 3

In [30]: string.count(a,'ab'[:])
Out[30]: 1

In [31]: string.count(a,'a'[:])
Out[31]: 1
```

Can anybody explain me why some times I am getting result as 1 and why sometimes 3 here. Overall I need to understand how this function works exactly ?

Comment: note that you don't need string module for this, using `'ab'.count('a')` for eg. is better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everytime you see a `3` as result, the second parameter was the empty string – you hide this facte by using strange slicings.  The empty string is considered to occur at the positions `0:0`, `1:1` and `2:2` for this example, so there are three occurrences.  In general, `string.count(s, "")` (or equivalently, `s.count("")`) will return `len(s) + 1`.

To explain how this result comes about, here is a (not very efficient) example implementation of `string.count()`:

```py
def count(s, sub):
    result = 0
    for i in range(len(s) + 1 - len(sub)):
        result += (s[i:i + len(sub)] == sub)
    return result
```

Comment: The OP also seems to think that the `start` and `end` parameters slice `sub`, not `s` (assuming that the pasted experiments were trying to understand the line that was bolded.)

Comment: (This does not honor the non-overlapping part though: `count("aaa", "aa")` yields `2` instead of `1`.)

Answer (score 2):

I think your error lies in misunderstanding the notation that the documentation uses.

> **string.count(s, sub[, start[, end]])** Return the number of
>   (non-overlapping) occurrences of substring sub in string s[start:end].
>   Defaults for start and end and interpretation of negative values are
>   the same as for slices.

The square brackets `[]` denote optional arguments. It is a short form for providing three different method signatures, they are not part of the actual syntax to invoke the method:

- `string.count(s, sub)`
- `string.count(s, sub, start)`
- `string.count(s, sub, start, end)`

> Defaults for start and end and interpretation of negative values are
>   the same as for slices.

This is slicing:

```
>>> "0123_3210"[:3] # from the first until the 3rd item, excluding it
'012'
>>> "0123_3210"[-3:] # from the 3rd-to-last until the end
'210'
>>> "0123_3210"[-3:-1] # from the 3rd-to-last until the end, excluding one item
'21'
>>> "0123_3210"[1:3] # from the second item until the 3rd, excluding it
'12
```

As you can see, when you use negative indexes it starts counting from the right end.

What is says is, that these are equivalent for both positive and negative of `start` and `end` respectively.

- `string.count(s[:], sub)` ≡ `string.count(s, sub)`
- `string.count(s[start:], sub)` ≡ `string.count(s, sub, start)`
- `string.count(s[start:end], sub)` ≡ `string.count(s, sub, start,end)`

Answer (score 1):

> [...] interpretation of negative values are the same as for slices

is for the third and forth optional arguments of the `string.count(...)` function.

```
In [1]: import string

In [2]: s = 'hello world'

In [3]: string.count(s, 'o')
Out[3]: 2

In [4]: string.count(s, 'o', 5, 9) # count from 6th to 10th characters
Out[4]: 1

In [5]: string.count(s, 'o', 5, 9) == string.count(s[5:9], 'o')
Out[5]: True

In [6]: string.count(s, 'o', -9, -5) # count from 3rd to 6th characters
Out[6]: 1
```

This is very different to search the empty string:

```
In [7]: string.count(s, 'o'[5:9]) == string.count(s, '') == (2 + (len(s) - 1))
Out[7]: True
```

(There are "empty strings" at the beginning, at the end and between each characters of `s`)

Answer (score 1):

It seems your confusion comes either from not being certain of how to use the slice notation, or not being clear on the behavior of **string.count()** with respect to the empty string.

I think you would be well served by reading http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings.

```
In [19]: a 
Out[19]: 'ab'
```

Okay.

```
In [23]: string.count(a,'ab'[1:3]) 
Out[23]: 1
```

'ab'[1:3] == 'b'. There is one instance of 'b' in 'ab'.

```
In [24]: string.count(a,'ab'[1:1]) 
Out[24]: 3
```

'ab'[1:1] == ''.

The count of '' in any string in python is equal to len(string)+1 UNLESS the string length is greater than INT_MAX (I believe), in which case  it returns INT_MAX.

You can see this in the Python source code here: http://svn.python.org/view/*checkout*/python/trunk/Objects/stringlib/count.h?content-type=text%2Fplain.

```
In [25]: string.count(a,'ab'[-1:1]) 
Out[25]: 3
```

'ab'[1:1] == ''. Once again, you are taking the count of ''.

```
In [26]: string.count(a,'ab'[-1:0]) 
Out[26]: 3
```

'ab'[1:1] == '', again.

```
In [27]: string.count(a,'ab'[1:4]) 
Out[27]: 1
```

'ab'[1:4] == 'b'.

```
In [28]: string.count(a,'ab'[1:100]) 
Out[28]: 1
```

'ab'[1:100] == 'b'.

```
In [29]: string.count(a,'ab'[100:100]) 
Out[29]: 3
```

'ab'[100:100] == ''.

```
In [30]: string.count(a,'ab'[:]) 
Out[30]: 1
```

'ab'[:] == 'ab'. There is one occurence of 'ab' in 'ab'.

```
In [31]: string.count(a,'a'[:]) 
Out[31]: 1
```

In this case 'a'[:] == 'a'. There is one occurences of 'a' in 'ab'.

Clearer?